# Radio box select search form

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, magento

Hello i have a search form in a mangeto website , http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro it looks like this :

```
<form id="search_mini_form">
<div class="form-search">
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <div class="input-box"><input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" class="input-text" autocomplete="off" lang="ro"></div>
    <button type="submit" title="Cauta" class="button"><span><span>Cauta</span></span></button>
    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none; "></div>
<input name="SE" type="radio" value="catalogsearch/result/">Produse
<input name="SE" type="radio" value="cauta">Site

    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var searchForm = new Varien.searchForm('search_mini_form', 'search', 'Cauta in magazin...');
        searchForm.initAutocomplete('http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro/catalogsearch/ajax/suggest/', 'search_autocomplete');
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
j("#search_mini_form").change(function() {
var action = j(this).val() == "Produse" : "Site";
j("#search_mini_form").attr("action",action);
});
 //]]>
 </script>
```

It should change the form action to "catalogsearch/result/" if "Produse" radio is checked and change form action to "cauta" if the "Site" radio is checked , well i get the following results with this code :
When i click "Produse" i get "http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro/?q=test+search&SE=catalogsearch%2Fresult%2F"
And when i click "Site" i get "http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro/?q=test+search&SE=cauta"
I need it to be like this "http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro/catalogsearch/result/?q=test%20query" for "Produse" and "http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro/cauta?q=test%20query" for "Site".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery("#search_mini_form input[type='radio']").change(function() {
    var action = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery("#search_mini_form").attr("action",action);
});

jQuery("#search_mini_form").submit(function() {
    jQuery("input[type='radio']", this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Comment: it works but when i search first for "Produse" and after i click the "Site" Button it goes http://upgrade.fisapacient.ro/catalogsearch/result/cauta?q=aaa

Comment: i have tried adding a j("#search_mini_form").removeAttr("action"); to clear the action but doesnt work. it does the same thing if i try to repeat search on "Produse" i don't know why but this doesn't happen with the "Site" button

Comment: ok i have fixed the problem by changing the URL of the product search form , the error was generated because of the "/" in the url but i have changed "catalogsearch/result/" to "cauta-produse" and it now works

Comment: Sorry, was afk for lunch break - glad you figured it out on your own ;)